# Why are the functions $y=x^{\sin^2(x)}+x^{\cos^2(x)}$ and $y=(x-2\sqrt{x}+1)\cos^2(2x)+2\sqrt{x}$ so similar?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I was just playing around with functions and plotting them in Desmos and I found that these functions are remarkably similar despite their totally different expressions. The functions are

$$y=x^{\sin^2(x)}+x^{\cos^2(x)}$$ and $$y=(x-2\sqrt{x}+1)\cos^2(2x)+2\sqrt{x}$$

Link to Desmos page:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/meyktbtz0i

Edit: They aren't exactly the same if you zoom in closer as pointed out to me.

Comment: Zoom in far enough.  You'll see that they aren't exactly equal.

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you put a backslash before common functions you get the correct font and spacing, so \sin (x) gives $\sin (x)$

Comment: What is your question? Are you wanting to verify your claim?

Comment: @RossMillikan thanks!

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh. Interesting. I guess it turns out to be some kind of close approximation.

Comment: @user1729 I was just curious that the second function seems to be the same as the first one; I thought there would be some proof that shows that they are the same, but JMoravitz pointed out that they aren't exactly equal.

Comment: @Bao Okay. You should edit your question to explain this then.

Comment: It's fascinating that the curves are so persistently close. I would urge you to edit the question to make it clearer that you (now) understand the functions are not the same, but would like to know why they are so similar. And please explain how you came to consider them.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to justify why the two equations are so close. I'll look into it.

Comment: An easier way to "see" where they are almost the same and where they are different is to draw the graph of $f(x)-g(x)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that

$$f(x)=x^{\sin^2(x)}+x^{\cos^2(x)}=x^{1-\cos^2(x)}+x^{\cos^2(x)}$$

$$g(x)=(x-2\sqrt{x}+1)\cos^2(2x)+2\sqrt{x}=$$

$$=(x-2\sqrt{x}+1)\cos^2(2x)+2\sqrt{x}(\cos^2(2x)+\sin^2(2x))=$$

$$=(x+1)\cos^2(2x)+2\sqrt{x}\sin^2(2x)$$

with

$$2\sqrt x \le f(x), g(x) \le x+1$$

and since, as noticed in the graph linked to your question, we have that

- at $x=\frac \pi 4 + \frac12k\pi$

$$f(x)=x^{\sin^2(x)}+x^{\cos^2(x)}=2\sqrt x \quad f'(x)=\frac1{\sqrt x}$$

$$g(x)=(x+1)\cos^2(2x)+2\sqrt{x}\sin^2(2x)=2\sqrt x \quad g'(x)=\frac1{\sqrt x}$$

- at $x=\frac \pi 2 + \frac12k\pi$

$$f(x)=x^{\sin^2(x)}+x^{\cos^2(x)}=x+1 \quad f'(x)=1$$

$$g(x)=(x+1)\cos^2(2x)+2\sqrt{x}\sin^2(2x)=x+1 \quad g'(x)=1$$

the two functions coincide in infinitely many points with the same slope at these points thus they appear very close one to each other.